# C# file transfer through sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, zip, mime-types

I have to make a client-server file sync application...I was wondering that instead of having a seperate mime type and code for every file type, is it possible to just zip the file types, transmit to server and unzip it?

Will it work or will I have to identify the mime type for each file and do code handling for each mime type?

Comment: If you are transferring via a socket, why do you need a MIME type? Just send the binary data, prefixed with well-defined information concerning the size and, if needed, file name.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets deal in bytes so it doesn't matter what format the file is sent in, as long as the client and server are aware of the protocol. You can create your own protocol. For example, it might be in the format of {messagelength},{mimetype},{fileasbytearray}. This way, your client knows how to parse the final message (ie first 4 bytes might length (assuming int), then your mimetype and then the actual byte array of the file).

If you're using the same format all the time, such as zip files, then you don't need the mime type. Just remember that if you plan on expanding on the future, it's a good idea to design your protocol to be easily expandable.

Comment: i understand that sockets deal in bytes, but once the bytes are received by the client, it must create a file and write those bytes in the file...at this point a mime type is required...

my problem is that i have too many file types to transfer, so i wanted to know if I can just zip all the files, transmit, receive, create file and unzip...will that work or I still need the mime types...

when I am unzipping on the client, i would need the file type then right?

Comment: Sending zip files is fine. You don't need to know the mime type in that case because you know that it's always a zip file. It doesn't matter what the zip file contains because you're sending the zip file itself. Assuming the sending has been succesful, the bytes received is a direct copy of the zip file sent. Therefore, your unzipper program knows how to read it automatically.